# UILabel shadow with CALayer doesn't draw

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'am trying to draw a shadow of a `UILabel` with the `CALayer` of the label.

Well, here is my code:

```
    nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.0, 2.0, 180.0, 40.0)];

    [nameLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-UltraLight" size:26.0]];
    [nameLabel setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [nameLabel setClipsToBounds:NO];
    [[nameLabel layer] setShadowColor:[UIColor blackColor].CGColor];
    [[nameLabel layer] setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(1.0, 2.0)];
    [[nameLabel layer] setShadowRadius:20.0f];
    [[nameLabel layer] setShadowOpacity:0.5f];
```

The label is contained in a `UIView`.
If I just add the `CALayer` (and hide the label itself) as a sublayer to the view, it shows just the text, but not the shadow.

Setting `setMasksToBounds` or `setShouldRasterize` doesn't help.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to decrease shadow radius or describe what you expected from a shadow with 20px radius.

Comment: 20px was just a test. I tested it with values between 3 and 20px. No value worked.

Comment: Check if it is `nil`, 3 is a quite large value for half-transparent shadow radius, especially if the background is not solid white (you can try 0).

Comment: Now this is awkward. Thanks a lot. It works with 1.0f. Post it as an answer and I'll upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positive values of `shadowRadius` blur the shadow a lot, small or zero values should be used for a clearly visible shadow.